# How to use MultiThreading in Android for an Event Handling Function (SensorListeners)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, events, sensors

I have an event handling mechanism in my Android code to dump the sensor values in a file. Right now, I'm doing it in the main UI thread and hence the UI button responsiveness is very sluggish and I would like to speed it up.

How can I use multithreading on event handling functions? I'm trying to do it like this:

1. Create a global variable writeNow.
2. When the sensor value changes, set WriteNow = true
3. Create a thread in the class which looks like this:

   ```
   Thread thread1 = new Thread()  
   {  
     public void run()  
     {  
       if(writeNow == true)  
         {  
           try 
           {  
               fos.write(s.getBytes());  
           } 
           catch (IOException e) 
           {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
           }  
           writeNow = false;  
         }  
     }  
    };
   ```

Thus, whenever writeNow is true, it will write to a File and then set WriteNow to false. However, I realize this is not the right approach, because the thread will execute once and then stop executing. When I tried a simple example with a while(true) and wait(), I found that the thread is interrupted millions of times.

So how do I enclose this event handling mechanism in a single thread, for speeding up a process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following approaches:

1. It looks like you're trying to keep your writer thread running all the time; what you can do is spawn the thread only when you need it. Take a look at the example in the Android documentation for [handling expensive operation in the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading).

   Here is the example from that page:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {

       [ . . . ]
       // Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
       final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

       // Create runnable for posting
       final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               updateResultsInUi();
           }
       };

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           [ . . . ]
       }

       protected void startLongRunningOperation() {

           // Fire off a thread to do some work that we shouldn't do directly in the UI thread
           Thread t = new Thread() {
               public void run() {
                   mResults = doSomethingExpensive();
                   mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
               }
           };
           t.start();
       }

       private void updateResultsInUi() {

           // Back in the UI thread -- update our UI elements based on the data in mResults
           [ . . . ]
       }
   }
   ```

   Since it doesn't look like you're doing anything in the UI thread once you finish writing you don't really need to bother with a `Handler`. But you might want to use it to display a `Toast` once the file has been written to.
2. On the other hand, if you still want to have a thread running, you might have it `sleep()` and periodically wake up and check the status of `writeNow`.

   ```
   Thread thread1 = new Thread()  
   {  
       public void run()  
       {  
           while(true)
           {
               if(writeNow == true)  
               {  
                   try 
                   {  
                       fos.write(s.getBytes());  
                   } 
                   catch (IOException e) 
                   {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                   }  

                   writeNow = false;  
               }

               try
               {
                   Thread.sleep(100); //sleep for 100 ms
               }
               catch (InterruptedException e) 
               {  
                    Log.d('', e.getMessage());  
               }  
           }
       }  
    };
   ```

   Note that this will quickly get complicated and you might lose the bytes you want to write if your thread is sleeping when new data comes in and when it wakes up, even newer data has been received and has overwritten the previous bytes. You'd need some sort of a queue to manage that.
3. I'm not sure what you were doing with the `wait()` but that should've also worked and is in fact, the approach for problems involving a consumer and producer. The idea is to have your thread synchronize and `wait()` on a shared object (like perhaps your queue of bytes); a second thread will call `notify()` on the shared object when there is data available to write and the writer thread will be woken up. The writer thread should then write and reloop. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify.shtml).

   As for the interruption of your thread, your thread may be interrupted for a number of reasons which is why it is good practice (especially when using `wait()`) to ensure that the condition you checked *before* you called `wait()` is still valid because you could've been woken because of either a call to `notify()/notifyAll()` or because of an interruption.

Comment: Why do I have to sleep for 100ms? Why not keep a while(true) running all the time? I actually tried this piece of code but the UI responsiveness doesn't improve at all...

Comment: If your thread doesn't `sleep` (and it doesn't have to be 100 ms, it depends on your application) it's not giving other threads a chance at running - and if it's the only thread hogging all the system resources you will see a general sluggishness on the device because the UI thread and other threads are unable to get enough CPU time. Take a look at [busy waiting](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Busy_waiting).

Comment: Did you try approach #1 or #3? `wait/notify` is a common approach to consumer-producer problems - see the tutorial I linked to. And the code in #1 is pretty much complete, you just need to move your write login in to the `run()` method there. If this still doesn't help then your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I used the wait/notify approach... it improved responsiveness quite a bit.. I used a synchronized(object) and waited/notified on that object and it worked great.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = null;

handler = new Handler();

//create another class for and make consrtuctor as u want. so that u can use that effectively.
//for example.                                                      

popupIndex = new IndexThread(handler,head, target,ltp,price,IndexNifty.this,columsView,call);           

popupIndex.setColumnViewexit(columsView);
handler.postDelayed(popupIndex, 300);


//another class
public IntraThread(Handler handler,String script,int target,int ltp,int price,Intraday intraday,TextView columsView,String call){
        super();
        this.target = target;
        this.ltp = ltp;
        this.price = price;     
        this.intraday = intraday;
        this.columsView = columsView;
        this.script= script;
        this.handler= handler;
        this.call= call;
}

public void run(){
// write ur code here....
}
```

Comment: see also [Acclerometer Sensor in Separate Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17513504/192373)