# Acclerometer Sensor in Separate Thread

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I am saving data from Accelerometer Sensor to Database, but I want to do it in a separate thread. I tried to search it on Internet but most of them uses the same thread.

Things I have tried:

```
SenSorEventListener sel;
    Thread A=new Thread(){
                public void run()
                {
                    sel=new SensorEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            double Acceleration,x,y,z;
                            x=event.values[0];
                            y=event.values[2];
                            z=event.values[2];
                            Acceleration=Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
                            db.addAccel(Acceleration);
                            Log.d("MESSAGE","SAVED");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            A.start();
            try {
                A.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sm.registerListener(sel,s,1000000);
}
```

I took a SensorEventListener, initialized it in a new Thread and then registering it with register listener.

Another approach:
I implemented Accelerometer class using Runnable interface, initialized everything in Constructor, so my run() method is blank, but this approach doesn't create a new Thread.

```
    Accelerometer(Context con,Database d)
        {   
            sm=(SensorManager)con.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            s=sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
            sm.registerListener(this,s,1000000);
            db=d;
        }
   void run()
   {}
```

I would be happy to try another approach, or to hear I am doing something wrong in the above approaches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to use `registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate, Handler handler)` and supply a `Handler` that is running on a background thread.

Create a `HandlerThread`, get its `Looper`, create a `Handler` supplying the looper.

This will let you receive the callbacks on the background thread.  When finished ensure you remove the listener and then call `Looper.quit()`, to exit the thread.

Comment: in order to exit, do we call `Looper.quit()` or the instance of `HandlerThread`, say `handlerThread.quit()`?

Comment: HandlerThread.quit() will call Looper.quit() on the reference of Looper it holds.  The function HandlerThread.quit() was added in a later API.